# Dropdown menu and input field work together using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown button and an input field. If you click on the button it shows a list of Names (that are written in JSON). I want to add the following things but I am not sure how to do it:

- When choosing a name I want it to appear in the input field.
- When writing in the input field I want the list to appear (with result that correspond to that letter).

I would prefer to do as much as possible with angular but of course i regular javascript or JQuery is required that's fine too. Let me know if you have questions.

[image]

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                 Name <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="x in Person">{{x.name }}</li>

                </ul>
   </div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
```

Comment: as a matter of interest where does your input box appear in the code you have provided above? Does the image you have posted correspond to this code?

Comment: Check out ui-select https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: I believe the code at the bottom of this link may be what you are looking for. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter Let me know if this is it, and if you are having difficulty implementing it I have done a jsfiddle that I can share with you if you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularStrap typeahead:  http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters on your ng-repeat to filter the options when typing on the input like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
 <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" id="dropdown1" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Name <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul aria-labelledby="dropdown1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:selectedPerson"><a ng-click="selectPerson(person)">{{person}}</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      <input id="personInput" ng-model="selectedPerson" ng-change="toogleDropdown()" type="text"  class="form-control">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.selectedPerson = "";

$scope.toogleDropdown = function(){
    if($scope.selectedPerson.length>3){
        $('#dropdown1').dropdown('toggle');
    }
    $('#personInput').focus();
}

$scope.selectPerson = function(person){
    $scope.selectedPerson = person;
}

$scope.persons = ['donald','polsie'];
});
```

[Heres a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/1447/)

Comment: This solution seemed good but it didn't change anything. It seems like the items of my dropdown menu are not clickable. The mouse doesn't get the shape of a hand when hovering it (The mouse get the shape of a hand when hovering a button). I put {{x.name}} within a-tags in order for the hovered item to be marked. That made it look nicer but it didn't solve my problems. Any ideas what I need to change?

Comment: Am I supposed to write something more to make this work? Controller?

Comment: Nop, only the "Person" array. the ng-click attribute doesnt change your cursor to pointer (hand), you have to do it manually with css or an a-tag, what other things beside the cursor are not working?

Comment: Yes that part I can change with CSS: The following still doesn't work: 1) When choosing a name I want it to appear in the input field. It doesn't.
2) When writing in the input field I want the list to appear (with result that correspond to that letter). This is not happening either.

Comment: Half the problem is solved. When clicking on a person from the dropdown list  he appears in the input field. This is good. However when writing a letter in the input field I want the dropdown list to appear. I want its content to change when letters are added or removed. Thank you.

Comment: That is working on the jsFiddle, I added a minimum of 3 characters to activate the dropdown you can change this to 1 character, try it

Comment: I copy pasted your code into my project. When I write the fourth letter I get the error message: TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function. Then nothing happens.

Comment: Check if you included bootstrap.js and jquery, it works fine on the fiddle

Comment: <script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> and <script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script> are both in the head of the file. Is that correct?

Comment: You are missing the bootstrap js

Comment: Sorry. I do have bootstrap.js too. Also in the head: <script
 src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>